# ParserError: Expected ';' but got '[' in my solidity contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am getting a syntax error in my sol contract, but I have rechecked the syntax and everything looks fine to me. So any help would be appreciated. This is my code:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solodity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

contract Record {

    struct MedRecord {
        string password;
        string name;
        address patient;
        address[] doctor;
    }
    mapping(address => MedRecord) internal medRecords;

    address[] public recordList;


    function addRecord(address _key, string memory password, string memory name) public {
        address docs[] = new; ////////////////////////ERROR LINE////////////////////
        medRecords[_key] = MedRecord(password, name, _key, []);
        recordList.push(_key);
    }

    function remove(address _key) public {
        delete medRecords[_key];
    }
    
    // function contains(address _key) public view returns (bool) {
    //     return MedRecords[_key][0] != '';
    // }
    
    function getByKey(address _key) public view returns (MedRecord memory) {
        return medRecords[_key];
    }
}
```

My error Message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct code:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0; // typo fixed here.

contract Record {

    struct MedRecord {
        string password;
        string name;
        address patient;
        address[] doctor;
    }
    mapping(address => MedRecord) internal medRecords;

    address[] public recordList;


    function addRecord(address _key, string memory password, string memory name) public {
        address[] memory docs; // needs to be completed with the array of addresses you'd like.
        medRecords[_key] = MedRecord(password, name, _key, docs);
        recordList.push(_key);
    }

    function remove(address _key) public {
        delete medRecords[_key];
    }
    
    // function contains(address _key) public view returns (bool) {
    //     return MedRecords[_key][0] != '';
    // }
    
    function getByKey(address _key) public view returns (MedRecord memory) {
        return medRecords[_key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an array for address then use brackets after address not after variable.
Do it like

```
address[] memory docs;
```